# Capture file from camera and resize by a memory efficient way in cordova/phonegap

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I'm searching since a while and only find the Resizer-Plugin (https://github.com/wymsee/cordova-imageResizer) for scaling. I take the picture from the camera plugin (https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera/blob/master/doc/index.md).

Is there any plugin or configuration to scale photos from device and camera without cropping them and only scale them if they are bigger then a default value in a memory efficient way or do I have to use the Resizer-Plugin for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I has found the solution in setting the targetWidth and targetHeight on the same value to get a correct scaled and not cropped image.